# Show users a different page (depending on their role) after logging in

Tags: users, redirection

In my site I have two different roles for users named recruiter and candidate. when they register their account they can choose their role (recruiter or candidate). And when they login my site I will check user is recruiter or candidate. after this check I will show them a different page (recruiter page and candidate page).

How to proceed with this?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Front Page module](https://www.drupal.org/project/front). Module description:

> The Front Page module allows for customised home pages dependant on
>   role. The pages can be of the following types:
>
> - Alias (only 2.x branch) - Allows for another Drupal path to be shown as the home page without redirecting the user.
> - Redirect - Allows you to redirect users to a local or remote URL.
> - Themed - Allows you to enter some static text that will be placed into the content area of a standard Drupal page.
> - Full - Allows for static content to be displayed to the screen as is. This method does not pass through Drupal's theming system.

One of the options should fit your need.

Comment: bro send me website links to more clears steps to proceed. Thanks Bro

Comment: There's a [README file](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/front/tree/README.txt) in the module.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple module for assigning role

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_ID_alter()
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Get the system roles.
  $roles = array_map('check_plain', user_roles(TRUE));

  $form['roles'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Roles'),
    '#default_value' => array(),
    '#options' => $roles,
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_user_insert()
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  // Save the role if it's set.
  if (isset($edit['roles'])) {
    // Push the roles to $account object so that user_save can get the role property.
    $account->roles[] = $edit['roles'];
  }
}
```

And after the user is logged in use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to redirect to any of your page

Answer (score 1):

These are both well used Drupal modules. Login destination does pretty much what you want, Login Toboggan doesn't quite do that but adds some nice signup features that you might want to use concurrently.

[Login destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination)

> The Login Destination module allows you to customize the destination
>   that a user is redirected to after logging in, registering to the site
>   (7.x), using a one-time login link or logging out (7.x). The
>   destination can be an internal page or an external URL. It is possible
>   to specify certain conditions like referring pages or user roles and
>   make the destination depend upon them. You may use PHP snippets to
>   provide custom conditions and destinations. It is also possible to
>   keep users on the currently visited page after logging in or out.

or

[Login toboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan)

> The LoginToboggan module offers several modifications of the Drupal
>   login system in an external module by offering the following features
>   and usability improvements:
>
> 1. Allow users to login using either their username OR their e-mail
>      address.
> 2. Allow users to login immediately. Provide a login form on
> 3. Access Denied pages for non-logged-in (anonymous) users.
> 4. The module
>      provides two login block options: One uses JavaScript to display the
>      form within the block immediately upon clicking "log in". The other
>      brings the user to a separate page, but returns the user to their
>      original page upon login.
> 5. Customize the registration form with two
>      e-mail fields to ensure accuracy.
> 6. Optionally redirect the user to a
>      specific page when using the 'immediate login' feature.
> 7. Optionally
>      redirect the user to a specific page upon validation of their e-mail
>      address.
> 8. Optionally display a user message indicating a successful
>      login.
> 9. Optionally combine both the login and registration form on one
>      page.
> 10. Optionally have unvalidated users purged from the system at a
>       pre-defined interval (please read the CAVEATS section of INSTALL.txt
>       for important information on configuring this feature!).
> 11. Integrates
>       with Rules module to do various tasks when a user validates via email
>       validation process (see http://drupal.org/node/880904 for an example)

Comment: Hi cozmo. Please try to avoid link-only answers. Better is to include some information from the linked resource. (Links can go down over time). Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Sorry, new to this!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest way to do it without installing additional modules: create a module with this code and specify inside the code role names and destinations:

```
function MY_MODULE_user_login(&$edit, $account)
{

    if (user_has_role_by_role_name('role_one', $account)) {
        drupal_goto('role_one_goes_here'); // relative path
    } elseif (user_has_role_by_role_name('role_two', $account)) {
        drupal_goto('role_two_goes_here'); // relative path
    }
}


function user_has_role_by_role_name($role_name, $user)
{
    $role_object = user_role_load_by_name($role_name);
    if (user_has_role($role_object->rid, $user)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this. Here is a rule (in Rules export format tht you can import in your own site using the Rules UI) that should be close to what you'd need (for a recruiter):

```
{ "rules_redirect_to_recruiter_content" : {
    "LABEL" : "Redirect recruiter to recruiter content",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "user_login" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : { "account" : [ "account" ], "roles" : { "value" : { "4" : "4" } } } }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "recruiter\/content" } } ]
  }
}
```

This rule assumes that the recruiter role has role id = 4 (change to whatever role id that fits). And the path (in the Rules Action) to redirect to is assumed to be `recruiter/content` (change that path to fit your needs).

You could create a similar rule for "Candidate", starting from a clone from the Recruiter role. Or you could use the the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module to consolidate both rules in a single one.